# "Error : 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'split'"

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman

I am trying create an API using Django and testing it using POSTMAN.

While trying to test the API using the below code i am getting error

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def predict_plant_disease(request):
    try:
      if request.body:
        request_data = request.data["plant_image"]
        image_data = request_data.split(';base64,')
        image_array,err_msg =image_converter.convert_image(request_data)
           if err_msg == None :
                model_file = f"{BASE_DIR}/ml_files/cnn_model.pkl"
                saved_classifier_model = pickle.load(open(model_file,'rb'))
                prediction = saved_classifier_model.predict(image_array) 
                label_binarizer = pickle.load(open(f"{BASE_DIR}/ml_files/label_transform.pkl",'rb'))
                return_data = {
                    "error" : "0",
                    "data" : f"{label_binarizer.inverse_transform(prediction)[0]}"
                }
           else :
                return_data = {
                    "error" : "4",
                    "message" : f"Error : {err_msg}"
                }
       else :
            return_data = {
                "error" : "1",
                "message" : "Request Body is empty",
            }
     except Exception as e:
            return_data = {
                  "error" : "3",
                  "message" : f"Error : {str(e)}",
            }
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(return_data), content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

I am getting the error as 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'split'" **at second line in the outer if loop.** 
Help me to solve this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNqj8.png)

Screen Shot showing the error while requesting for the result from POSTMAN API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From screen-shot, it is clear that u are giving input in the form of file whereas in the code the image is accepted as a encoded base64 form.

Give the input as encoded base64 form of the image. This encoding can be done online using any encoding website.
https://www.base64-image.de/